# AES decryption using PHP

Tags: php, encryption, cryptography, aes, phpseclib

I'm trying to decrypt image encrypted with AES using PHP. I tried it using [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/) like this (aeskey is in hexadecimal):

```
 $aes = new Crypt_AES(CRYPT_AES_MODE_CBC);
 $aes->setIV("00000000000000000000000000000000");
 $aes->setKey($aeskey);
 $aes->setKeyLength(256);

 $decryptedMessage =  $aes->decrypt(base64_decode($data));
```

But nothing is returned. I also tried it using [this classes](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/4238-PHP-Encrypt-and-decrypt-data-with-AES-in-pure-PHP.html)

```
$Cipher = new AES(AES::AES256);
$content = $Cipher->decrypt(base64_decode($data), $aeskey);
$content = $Cipher->hexToString($content);
```

The result was too short. I know that data and AES key are ok, I tested it in [AES calculator](http://extranet.cryptomathic.com/) and I got data in hexa, converted to binary and when I returned it with image header in PHP, I got the image. Could you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The question is, how was the image encrypted and encoded. We can't know. That's were you come in.

Comment: I didn't encrypt it, I only got information how to decrypt.
I have encrypted data in base64 form, and AES key of length 256, also in base64.
I know that it was encrypted using CBC mode, and the format of the image is jpeg. I think these information are sufficient to get the image (and I checked that that at website I mentioned - I got the right decripted data), although I can't decrypt it using PHP, don't know why.

Comment: But you have to know how it was encrypted. For example, is the `$key` 32 byte long? Is it encoded somehow or is a raw byte string? Is the IV supposed to consist of sixteen 0x00 bytes or 32 zero characters? You can find out how the "AES calculator" does it.

Comment: Maybe you need to be doing this?: `pack('H*', '00000000000000000000000000000000')` and `pack('H*', $aeskey)`?